# Display Image With Label In Radiobutton - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, radiobuttonlist, yii2-basic-app

Due to some requirement, I need to show Image with label in radio button list.

I searched [How to insert an Image List into a radioButtonList?](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16840-solved-how-to-insert-an-image-list-into-a-radiobuttonlist/). And, incorporated the changes.

**View**

```
<?php
$model->pay_type = 1;
echo $form->field($model, 'pay_type')->radioList($model->paymentOptionRadioButtonList())->label(false);
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
public function paymentOptionRadioButtonList(){
  $payment_options = $params->payment_type;

  foreach($payment_options as $key => $val){
    $payment_options[$key] = $val.yii\helpers\Html::img('www.dummy.com/'.'company-default-logo.jpg');
  }
  return $payment_options;
}

?>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Instead of showing image, It's showing `<img src="www.dummy.com/company-default-logo.jpg" alt="">`

Is there any parameters I need to pass in radio button list to show image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should disable `encode` option for radioList to show raw HTML.
e.g.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'pay_type')->radioList($model->paymentOptionRadioButtonList(), ['encode' => false])->label(false);
```

More info here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#radioList()-detail

Comment: Thank You @Dmitriy.